# Type Hierarchy stopped working in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

As you can see in the Type Hierarchy (right side), I don't see any dropdown button which can show `ImageProvider`'s subclasses.

However, you can see (in the middle window) that there are many classes which extends `ImageProvider`. I should be seeing them in the Type Hierarchy but I don't. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the log? `Help | Show Log in Finder/Explorer`

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers I only see this line after performing the action `[4524161]   INFO - .script.IdeScriptEngineManager - javax.script.ScriptEngineManager initialized in 200 ms` -- so no error. I also want to mention that every time I open AS, the above hierarchy works for the first time, doing it second time causes the issue.

Comment: What does it show if you choose -for example- `ResizeImage`, and fetch its Supertypes Hierarchy? Does it show you `ImageProvider` as a SuperType?

Comment: @PierreJanineh I think there's something internal related to this, you can follow [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5899).